grab tool doesn't grab except in a few spots
I am new to Blender. I am trying to learn how to sculpt, but my grab tool only seems to grab a few seemingly preselected vertices. So, when I am trying to create a head and place where the skull connects to the neck or when I try to create a jaw line, the spot or dot that shows where I am grabbing only grabs at a few places and I can not do what I am attempting to do.

As you can see in the pic, I have the grab tool over the shape but no dot. But that dot will show up over some spaces. Why and what am I doing incorrectly?

Without images of your object, preferably in Edit mode, it's difficult to guess but it sounds as if you have a low poly mesh with too few vertices in it.

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Make sure the normals are pointing the right way (outwards)
